# infragistics get clientID of dropdown in Rowedit template

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

i have a infragistics web grid which has row edit template.
Row edit template contains drop down list. Now when i change the selected index of drop down..
i need to get the client id of the drop down..
the web grid is in Content place holder..

i am using the below code..

ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_webModGrid_ctl00_ddlScope

but it is giving error..

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use the switch 'ClientIDMode' and its value Static

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to evaluate the ClientID property of the required control (and its client-side tag object) in the following manner:

```
var clientID = '<%=ddlScope.ClientID%>';
var element = document.getElementById(clientID);
if (element) {
}
```

Otherwise, if the DropDownList is placed into the INamingContainer, it is possible to render the corresponding client-side object from the page’s code behind by handling the control’s Init event and using the ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript method in the following manner:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlScope" runat="server" OnInit="ddlScope_Init">
</asp:DropDownList>

protected void ddlScope_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    string script = string.Format("var _{0} = document.getElementById('{1}');", ddl.ID, ddl.ClientID);
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "ANY_KEY", script, true);
}

var element = _ddlScope;
alert(element);
```

Does it make a sense?

Comment: i get the below error.. The name 'ddlScope' does not exist in the current context

for some reason it is not picking up the dropdown id

Comment: @Goutham: Try to use another approach - Refer to the updated post.

Comment: i got the null in alert.. am i missing something. i have enable event validation = false on my page

Comment: @Goutham: Do not forget to make your questions as “answered” if the replays were helpful :)