# validating asp.net textBox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have an asp.net TextBox control on my page and a search button whenever user clicks on the search button i want to validate the TextBox for Blank. i want to use a onClientClick event and pass the parameter as my Javascript function will be going to be called from external JS.

Here's what I tried.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="search" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function voidsearch(s) {
        alert(document.getElementById(s).value);
    }
</script>

<asp:ImageButton ID="img1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Dotnetnuke.ico" 
    OnClientClick="voidsearch('<%= search.ClientID %>'); return false;" />
```

but this is throwing error. Object Required. i also passed this.search.. but same error. i dont understand why i am getting this error as i have first declared control and then called its ID.

Please anyone help me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the “search” TextBox is placed onto INamingContainer, so it is ClientID property cannot be evaluated. Use the approach, described in the [infragistics get clientID of dropdown in Rowedit template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364426/infragistics-get-clientid-of-dropdown-in-rowedit-template/5364489#5364489) thread:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="search" runat="server" OnInit="search_Init"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="img1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Dotnetnuke.ico" 
    OnClientClick="voidsearch();" return false;" />

protected void search_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
    string script = string.Format("var _{0} = document.getElementById('{1}');", txt.ID, txt.ClientID);
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "ANY_KEY", script, true);
}

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function voidsearch() {
    alert(_search);
    alert(_search.value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Validate on blank text box on button click in asp.net

```
<asp:textbox id="name" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
```

create JavaScript function for validate textbox

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function validate()
      {
         if(document.getElementByID("<%=name.ClientID%>").value=="")
           {
              alert("Please enter something");
              document.getElementByID("<%=name.ClientID%>").focus();
              return false;
           }
           return true;
      }
</script>
```

call function on button click:

```
<asp:button id="btn1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return validate()"></asp:button>
```