# Creating an ASP.NET User Control With a Javascript API

Tags: javascript, asp.net, api, user-controls

I'm basically trying to figure out a good/clean way to organize controls that would have a public API like this:

```
<script>
    function buttonClicked() {
        var myUserControl = SomehowGetReferenceToThisUserControl("UserControl");

        myUserControl.AjaxReload();
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:buttonClicked()">Refresh the User Control!</a>
<myControls:MyUserControl ID="UserControl" runat="server" />
```

I've seen some 3rd party controls that our team uses such as Telerik and DevExpress that have similar functionality, but I have no idea how it is implemented. Can anyone provide some insight on a good/clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: doesn't the extenders do what you are asking, they have clean api, they interact with web service, they can re-render also cause postback.

Comment: @Deeptechtons: You tell me. If they do, I don't know about them or what feature they have that I can use for this. Care to provide an answer about it?

Comment: i surely do have answer, just that if you knew extenders and it didn't work out for you i would be wasting everyone else time, i will update you with a code example.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to create / initialize data unique in the WebUserControl’s content (to avoid issues with the use multiple instances of this WebUserControl):

Register the startup script to create the javascript programmatic object (see the [validating asp.net textBox using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655739/validating-asp-net-textbox-using-javascript/5655916#5655916) thread) to instantiate WebUserControl reference (like DevExpress recommends in the [www.devexpress.com/kb=K18373](http://www.devexpress.com/kb=K18373) KB).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and fortunately I'd found interesting blog post - [Dynamically create ASP.NET user control using ASP.NET Ajax and Web Service.](http://weblogs.asp.net/sanjeevagarwal/archive/2008/07/22/Dynamically-create-ASP.NET-user-control-using-ASP.NET-Ajax-and-Web-Service.aspx)