# getElementById works in one environment, but not in another

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis

I have javascript code that clicks a button for me.
It works when hosted on machine 1, but when hosted on machine 2 the .GetElementByID call returns Null.

**The js code looks like this**:

```
function ClickAButtonForMe() {
    var btn = null;
    var btnClientID = '<%= btnReset.ClientID %>';

    //this comes back with a valid clientID on **both** machines
    alert("btnClientID=/" + btnClientID + "/, nodevalue=/" + nodeValue + "/");

    if (0 < btnClientID.length) {
        btn = document.getElementById(btnClientID);
    }
    if (btn != null) {
        //on machine 1, this works as expected
        btn.click();
    }
    else {
        //on machine 2, i come here
        alert("button not found");
    }
}
```

**The button declaration in my ascx file looks like this:**

```
    <div id="div_Reset" class="eventManagementButtonWrapper" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button class="eventManagementButton" ID="btnReset" ValidationGroup="None" runat="server"
                Text="Reset" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

In other words, I can get a clientid for my button in **both** environments.  But when I try to actually grab the button itself, it fails on machine 2.

Can anyone suggest possible things to look at when figuring out the cause of this discrepancy?  I've tried changing the ClientIDMode to "Static", which does nothing except change the clientID in the first debug message.

Comment: What do you want the button to do? There are approaches that do not depend on grabbing element IDs.

Comment: What's different about machine 1 and 2? Also, is this only meant to work in IE? `click()` is IE-specific.

Comment: @Diodeus - the bigger picture is there are two TreeView controls on the screen.  Clicking the button slides selected nodes from the tree on the left into the tree on the right.  I'm trying to auto-slide them over by making that action fire when the user clicks the tree itself.  The functionality works on my local machine - but not on the deployment machine.

Comment: @GGG - There are probably quite a few differences, frankly - one is my local, the other is a server.  The code as shown currently works in firefox on my local, but fails in IE and firefox on the server.

Comment: I don't... I don't think I can help you. I can't fathom why a web browser would be running on a server :(

Comment: Have you verified at the HTML output is the same? Copy them both to text files (using the browser "view source") and compare them. Make sure that there is nothing else different.

Comment: @GGG - the browser is running on my local machine in both cases.  The same page is deployed in my local and on the server - when I navigate to the page hosted on the server, the getElementById comes back null.  When I navigate to the page hosted on my local, it comes back with a valid button.

Comment: @JosephStyons aha, I see... you might want to be a little more specific in your question, I assumed you were talking about one server and two clients. Maybe something like "it works when served from machine 1" or "it works on server 1".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the "**<%= btnReset.ClientID %>**" expression produces the same ClientID values in both cases. It looks like you are using this markup inside WebUserControl, whose ID (and the button’s ClientID as well) is computed accordingly.

As a universal solution, you can use my approach from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655739/validating-asp-net-textbox-using-javascript/5655916#5655916) thread:

```
<asp:Button ... ID="btnReset" OnInit="btnReset_Init" />

protected void btnReset_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string script = string.Format("var _{0} = document.getElementById('{1}');", btn.ID, btn.ClientID);
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "ANY_KEY", script, true);
}

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ClickAButtonForMe() {
    //alert(_btnReset);
    _btnReset.click();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is strange. 
Have you tried changing the ClientIDMode to "Static" and changing this:

```
'<%= btnReset.ClientID %>'
```

to just:

```
btnReset
```

Once ClientIDMode is "Static", asp doesn't add anything to the control id and leaves it as you named it.

In my experience when '<%=' doesn't work I try using '<%#' (not hash tag). However, this may fix the problem on one machine and create it on the other. So try my first suggestion and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions for some things which could go wrong and cause environment specific discrepancies, note: most of these are not specific to just your problem.

- Clear cache on all browers.
- Check the versions of all browsers.
- Compare the output HTML in the browsers.
- Is it the same (or relevantly similar) user logged in.
- Are they hitting the same page?
- Is it the same url, or two different hosted copies of the same code?

  - If this is different copies of the code, make sure it is the same version
- Depending on the environment (and the type of application) do an IIS reset to make sure the correct dlls are loaded.
- Are you running a debug/release version on one of the environments?
- Are you running IN debug on one of the environments?
- Is the DOM fully loaded in both cases? (race condition?)

Answer (score 0):

Just one scenario will cause this situation on different machines:

"You call ClickAButtonForMe function while DOM is not ready"

Comment: That makes sense, but this is a user-initiated action that happens many seconds after the page has finished loading.  Is there anything that could cause the DOM to remain unready for an extended period of time?